# How do I use the Gson converter in RetroFit?

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit

I'm making a simple RetroFit application for educational purposes, and use IntelliJ IDEA as my IDE.

I have imported the Retrofit library properly (at least I think I have) but I'm not able to get the Gson Converter package. I have the gson.jar from google installed but nowhere in either of these libraries is there a class called "GsonConverterFactory", which is required for me to parse JSON.

Edit: I'm on Windows.

Answer (score 22):

Add `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'` to your `build.gradle` file and get the dependency resolved or add corresponding jars to your bulid path.

then use `GsonConverterFactory.create()`  to get the `Converter Factory`

I tried using `2.0.0-beta1`  but it gave me an illegal type conversion error for factory as given below, so moved to `2.0.0-beta2`

```
  error: method addConverterFactory in class Builder cannot be applied to   given types;
    required: Factory
    found: GsonConverterFactory
    reason: actual argument GsonConverterFactory cannot be converted to Factory by method invocation conversion
```

So my suggestion is to use `2.0.0-beta2`

my build.gradle has following dependencies to resolve retrofit.

```
 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'  
 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
```

Comment: answer by iagreen will not work for retrofit beta2.. If retrofit2 is used we need to use converter-gson beta 2 as said by @manoj..

Comment: got the error - failed to resolve - for these above dependecies

Answer (score 20):

If you are using retrofit 2, you need to include the `convert-gson` package.  For gradle builds, you can add `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta3'` to your dependencies section.

For other build systems, or to download the jar, checkout the Maven Central [convert-gson](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22converter-gson%22) page.

Answer (score 15):

in your Module:app build.gradle add

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:[retrofit2 version]'
```

the version above is same with your retrofit2 version, so for example your retrofit2 version is 2.1.0, than your build.gradle should be like this :

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

Comment: This worked for me - specifying that they have to be exactly the same

Answer (score 14):

Try this

```
/* JSON */
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'

// >Retrofit & OkHttp
compile ('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3') {
    // exclude Retrofit’s OkHttp peer-dependency module and define your own module import
    exclude module: 'okhttp'
}
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'
```