# Can't resolve converter-gson package

Tags: android, retrofit

This is followup question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32428472/how-do-i-use-the-gson-converter-in-retrofit). I had a similar problem so when I searched SO I got this answer which says to include `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta1'`in the `build.gradle` but when I sync my gradle file it repeatedly says `failed to resolve`. I followed every method on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28493470/gradle-failed-to-resolve-library-in-android-studio) but it still does not work. What to do ?

Of course the last resort is to manually download the `gson-converter` and include it in the project but why is the gradle not working ?

Edit: I am including the screenshot of my `gradle`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was happening because I was running Internet from a place where I had to run on proxy. Once I connected to a connection (which didn't require proxy) the gradle sync worked !